# Can doxygen set custom permissions on the files it creates?

Tags: linux, doxygen

Have a source repository that I run through doxygen every now and then, which generates html in my public_html directory. Find myself having to change umask and hack the primary group in bash like this, which works:

```
echo "umask $UMASK; doxygen include_config.conf" | newgrp $GROUP
```

But it seems clunky and I can't help wondering if there's some configuration setting or option switch for doxygen to set UID/group and permissions directly on all the files/directories it generates? It's so frequently used for generating HTML on websites that almost everybody will need to e.g. have the output world-readable. Have searched the web, config file and man page to no avail.

**Update**: Was hoping to find some builtin feature, but looks like there is none. After some iterations this wrapper seems to do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT_PATH=/path/to/output
CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/include_config.conf
GROUP=somegroup
PERM=750
UMASK=027 

if [[ ! -e $OUTPUT_PATH ]]; then mkdir $OUTPUT_PATH; fi
chmod $PERM $OUTPUT_PATH
chmod g+s $OUTPUT_PATH
chgrp $GROUP $OUTPUT_PATH
umask $UMASK
doxygen $CONFIG_PATH
```

It's a bit more robust, portable and less clunky than the original script, while still working in one pass and without race conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's no way to tell Doxygen to set the ownership details of the generated files.  Considering that Doxygen runs on systems that don't have any notion of Linux-style filesystem permissions, I'd be surprised if that sort of thing was built into the application.  It should be trivial, though, to write a simple script that builds the documentation and automatically adjusts the permissions:

```
#!/bin/bash

doxygen include_config.conf
chgrp -R $GROUP $PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FOLDER
chmod -R $UMASK $PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FOLDER
```

**Update:**
In response to your comments (I admit it's off-topic a bit):
I recommend against using `newgrp` to do this.  It's an obsolete command that hearkens back to the old UNIX days when you could only be in one group at a time.  It's possible to run into some strange problems when using it on modern systems.  If you add the following before the `doxygen` call, anything created in the directory will inherit the group of the parent folder (which is essentially what you want):

```
mkdir $PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FOLDER
chgrp $GROUP $PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FOLDER
chmod g+s $PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FOLDER
```

The `chgrp` after running Doxygen will no longer be needed.  As a bonus, it doesn't alter the group ID of your current login session or of running processes and doesn't fork a sub-shell (`newgrp` will usually do one of those two).

Comment: OK guess I'm out of luck then and will stick to my umask/newgrp script. I won't be using chgrp and chmod because then it takes three passes over all files instead of one and also it'd have a race condition in my case since I'm actually setting more restrictive permissions.

Comment: Hadn't heard about `setgid` behaviour on directories; that's a neat feature. Will still need the umask, but it's a bit less clunky this way.